# Laravel Trait not found PHP Fatal Error

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, traits, laravel-testing

I am working on a project which has Laravel 5.3 version and using [Laravel Infyom Generator](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/), somehow it generated all these traits and other test files such as (ApiTest, RepositoryTest, ...etc). when I try to run **PHPUNIT** I am getting this error Can someone help me to find out why I am getting this error?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'MakeCustomerTrait' not found in C:\Users\ahmed\dev\gamla\tests\CustomerApiTest.php on line 8

Fatal error: Trait 'MakeCustomerTrait' not found in C:\Users\ahmed\dev\gamla\tests\CustomerApiTest.php on line 8
```

I want to start making new tests for my project do I need to delete these files? because it keeps giving me that error?

screenshot of **CustomerApiTest** code:
[image]

**MakeCustomerTrait**

```
<?php

use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Repositories\CustomerRepository;

trait MakeCustomerTrait
{
    /**
     * Create fake instance of Customer and save it in database
     *
     * @param array $customerFields
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function makeCustomer($customerFields = [])
    {
        /** @var CustomerRepository $customerRepo */
        $customerRepo = App::make(CustomerRepository::class);
        $theme = $this->fakeCustomerData($customerFields);
        return $customerRepo->create($theme);
    }

    /**
     * Get fake instance of Customer
     *
     * @param array $customerFields
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function fakeCustomer($customerFields = [])
    {
        return new Customer($this->fakeCustomerData($customerFields));
    }

    /**
     * Get fake data of Customer
     *
     * @param array $postFields
     * @return array
     */
    public function fakeCustomerData($customerFields = [])
    {
        $fake = Faker::create();

        return array_merge([
            'name' => $fake->word,
            'address_street' => $fake->word,
            'address_zip' => $fake->word,
            'address_city' => $fake->word,
            'address_country' => $fake->word,
            'shipping_address_street' => $fake->word,
            'shipping_address_zip' => $fake->word,
            'shipping_address_city' => $fake->word,
            'shipping_address_country' => $fake->word,
            'contact_person_id' => $fake->randomDigitNotNull,
            'created_at' => $fake->word,
            'updated_at' => $fake->word
        ], $customerFields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use complete namespace of the trait or define it in the use statement in your file. For global name space use it like `\MakeCustomerTrait`.

Comment: Can you write it here to understand what you mean?

Comment: I have updated the comment. Please see if it works.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error !

Comment: Have you written both of these class on your own?

Comment: I mentioned up, when I generate a new Model/Controller using **Generator Command** from InfyomLab all these tests generated by itself

Comment: updated it to global space name still
[Check It](http://i.imgur.com/lZyMU22.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is happening is here is autoloader is unable to resolve the class in your code. Laravel uses PSR-4 standards to autoload classes which needs fully qualified name spaces for the class which also represents the path of the file which holds the class.

See it this way that if you want to load a class inside your Laravel app directory at the following address :

```
app/repositories/users/UserRoleRepository.php
```

You will specify the namespace of your class like `App\repositories\users` with class name `UserRoleRepository` so the autoloader can load your class. Otherwise you have to include the file of your class manually.

You can register custom autoloads in your `composer.json` and by running the following command `composer dump-autoload`.

You can find more about it over internet [like this](http://alanstorm.com/laravel_5_autoloader/)

Hope it would help.

Comment: I already have **"App\\": "app/"** in my composer.json, Can I add more than one? Please can you show it to me I really got headache since morning :/

Comment: I added this **"Tests\\": "tests/"** as well, then spefity the namespace like this : **use Tests\Traits\MakeCustomerTrait;** but this time I am getting this error **PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Tests\Traits\MakeCustomerTrait' not found in C:\Users\ahmed\dev\myfurhat\tests\CustomerApiTest.php on line 8

Fatal error: Trait 'Tests\Traits\MakeCustomerTrait' not found in C:\Users\ahmed\dev\myfurhat\tests\CustomerApiTest.php on line 8**

Comment: You can always manually include the files of your trait using php's `include` method. It would be okay for test run.